# SQL Server UPDATE: set column if parameter is not null

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-update

I have a stored procedure that is meant to insert or update to a table depending on whether or not a value exists for a column. This is working fine except I only want to set the value of certain columns if a parameter has been passed. This is because I don't want to override the existing column value with null.

Below is an the idea of the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[p_SaveState]
   @Foo             nvarchar(50),
   @Bar             nvarchar(20) = null,
   @Something       nvarchar(20) = null
AS
BEGIN
   IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP(1) Foo FROM dbo.[State] WHERE Bar = @Bar)
   BEGIN
       UPDATE [dbo].[State]
       SET Bar = @Bar, 
           Something = @Something
       WHERE (--condition--)
   END
   ELSE
   BEGIN
      ... -- INSERT statement goes here
```

I am trying to accomplish something like this:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[State]
SET Bar = @Bar, 
    IF (@Something IS NOT NULL) Something = @Something
 WHERE (--condition--)
```

But I don't believe I can use CASE because I don't have the original value to set without performing a select.

How can I achieve this affect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ISNULL` will work fine here:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[State]
SET Bar = @Bar, 
    Something = ISNULL(@Something,Something)
WHERE...
```

Answer (score 2):

**[COALESCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** will do it for you!

```
UPDATE [dbo].[State]
SET Bar = @Bar, 
    Something = COALESCE(@Something,Something)
WHERE (--condition--)
```

Answer (score 2):

You *could* use `CASE`, like so...

```
UPDATE [dbo].[State]
SET Bar = @Bar, 
    Something = CASE WHEN @Something IS NOT NULL THEN @Something ELSE Something END
WHERE (--condition--)
```

This will set the value of `Something` to your variable value if it's `NOT NULL`, but will use the original value if it is `NULL`.

The same can be achieved more concisely using  `ISNULL` though, like so:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[State]
SET Bar = @Bar, 
    Something = ISNULL(@Something, Something)
WHERE (--condition--)
```